# I am getting a 500 response. Is the way I am trying this wrong? Or is there something I'm missing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm making a game project. I have everything working to where you can create a character, and it posts okay to the database, and I can see the characters I've created on an endpoint with all the details included.

Where it doesn't work anywhere else is where I have things shifted from a context state to a separate context state for a 'character sheet' state. All the data successfully goes to my character sheet, and console.logs support everything is properly showing up, but it won't post to my url.

My model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const characterSheetSchema = new Schema({
  characterPowers: {},
  characterInventory: {},
  characterArmor: {},
  characterShield: {},
  characterWeapon: {},
  characterCoin: {},
  characterHp: {},
  characterStats: {},
  characterExperience: { type: Number },
  characterRace: {},
  characterClass: {},
  characterAge: {
    type: Number,
  },
  characterName: {
    type: String,
  },
  characterDescription: {
    type: String,
  },
  characterLevel: { type: Number },
});

module.exports = CharacterSheet = mongoose.model(
  "charactersheet",
  characterSheetSchema
);
```

My routes:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const CharacterSheet = require('../../models/chracterSheet/characterSheet.model')

router.post("/createcharactersheet", (req, res) => {
    try {
        let {
            characterPowers,
            characterInventory,
            characterArmor,
            characterShield,
            characterWeapon,
            characterCoin,
            characterHp,
            characterStats,
            characterExperience,
            characterRace,
            characterClass,
            characterAge,
            characterName,
            characterDescription,
            characterLevel
        } = req.body

        const newCharacterSheet = new CharacterSheet({
            characterPowers,
            characterInventory,
            characterArmor,
            characterShield,
            characterWeapon,
            characterCoin,
            characterHp,
            characterStats,
            characterExperience,
            characterRace,
            characterClass,
            characterAge,
            characterName,
            characterDescription,
            characterLevel
        })

        const savedCharacterSheet = newCharacterSheet.save()

        res.json(savedCharacterSheet)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({err: err.message})
    }
    
})

router.get('/viewcharactersheets', (req, res) => {
    CharacterSheet.find({}, function(err, charactersheets) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            return res.json({charactersheets: charactersheets})
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

My post request:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/characters/createcharactersheet", {
      characterPowers: characterSheet.characterPowers,
      characterInventory: characterSheet.characterInventory,
      characterArmor: characterSheet.characterArmor,
      characterShield: characterSheet.characterShield,
      characterWeapon: characterSheet.characterWeapon,
      chacterCoin: characterSheet.characterCoin,
      characterHp: characterSheet.characterHp,
      characterStats: characterSheet.characterStats,
      characterExperience: characterSheet.characterExperience,
      characterRace: characterSheet.characterRace,
      characterClass: characterSheet.characterClass,
      characterAge: characterSheet.characterAge,
      characterName: characterSheet.characterName,
      characterDescription: characterSheet.characterDescription,
      characterLevel: characterSheet.characterLevel,
    });
```

[My Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RUSq.png)

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpEwh.png)

[POST error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvVJe.png)

[Uncaught in promise error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjUl7.png)

Everything else works and goes into my restful api, but for a reason unknown to me, it won't post to my createcharactersheet document or api.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a message with your 500 response?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts It's 500 (Internal Server Error) and also Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: Could you add the whole error you're getting in your route?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I added links to the images of my terminal and my console, because my terminal doesn't show any backend errors when I try to do what I'm doing. It's only the console error. If that's not what you meant, then I'm not getting any other errors.

Comment: If you expand that POST request in the browser console, are you receiving a response with the error from the backend?

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts I added images of the errors I got on the console. I still have nothing on the backend giving errors in my terminal like I linked. Sorry about not giving all of this. I'm learning this backend stuff as I go!

Comment: Don't worry about it! In Chrome, there's a Network tab so you can see the contents of request and responses. If you look for your request in there, you can what the server is sending back. It may also be helpful to log the error on the server-side.

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts Alright. I got my error not showing up now. I think I had something out of place. Not 100% sure what I did. But that's cleared up. Thanks to you I know I'm getting *something* it's just not getting what I'm trying to post. I'll work on that next, but that helps so much. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose `Model.save()` returns an `Promise` to try to use `async/await`

async/await way:

```js
router.post("/createcharactersheet", async(req, res) => {
   ...
    try {
        const newCharacterSheet = new CharacterSheet({
            ...
        })
        await newCharacterSheet.save()
        res.status(201).json(newCharacterSheet)
    } catch (error) {
       res.status(500).send(e.message)
    {
})
```

or (im not sure)

```js
const savedCharacterSheet = newCharacterSheet.save()
savedCharacterSheet
    .then(saved =>
        res.json(saved)
    )
    .catch(e =>
        res.status(500).send(e.message)
    )
```

#### Edit

Aslo log you errors

```js
catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: I didn't think I needed to put async await on that one because I did it differently on the one that worked, hah! But that is doing better now, at least. At the very least, my error is gone, I'm just playing around until I can get the data posted

Comment: This did it for me. I figured out I was missing a property for my state object when I was posting. As soon as I added it in the POST request and added the async/await, it did the trick. Thank you!